# Match new session to old session in php and redirect to correct page

Tags: php, session

i got a situation when user email and password is in session on page editProfile.php with id. e.g.  ../editProfile.php?id=17 and can update his own profile,

but if i change the url id value like ../editProfile.php?id=18 .. this can also update others information. why?

so, my question is how to redirect to other page if anyone change the id value 
or how to match session and then redirect.

Thanks

Comment: You can check session user id with the one fetched from url. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check id in session with the one get from url like;

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_GET["id"];
// I assume you have user id in session also
if (!empty($_SESSION["user_id"] && $_SESSION["user_id"] == $id)) {
    // Do your updates here
} else {
    header("Location: other_page.php");
    exit;
}
```

**Edit:** If you have no `user id` in session, you can set in while making user logged in or you can get it on the flyw like;

```
$user_id = get_user_id($_SESSION["username"], $_SESSION["password"]); // You can write a function to get user id
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;

if (!empty($_SESSION["id"] && $_SESSION["id"] == $id)) {
    // Do your updates here
} else {
    header("Locatio: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: well id is not in session yet..  im trying

Comment: @FarwallGhost If you have no id in session, you can set it in login handler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you are successfully logging in , you need to set this session variable like this on your login page..

```
$_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id; // Say , if it is 17 in this case..
```

So coming to your above scenario.. You could change your `editprofile.php` to look like this with the functionality

**`editprofile.php`**

```
<?php
session_start();

$userid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "Not Set";

if($userid=="Not Set" || (int)$_SESSION['user_id']!=$userid)
{
  die("You don't have access !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your place i'd use `check_session_id_from_db($ses_id)` to check if the `id` exists in this session

```
<?php 
$ses_id = session_id(); 
$bsid_exists = false; 
$bsid_exists = check_session_id_from_db($ses_id); 
 if ($bsid_exists){ 
 //This is a reentry and the session already exists 
 // create a new session ID and start a new 
session_regenerate_id();         
$ses_id = session_id(); 
 } 
?>
```

check more about this method here: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.session-id.php

for more about sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.session.php